# PostgreSQL count array values

Tags: sql, postgresql

What I would like is to count the array elements which corresponds to true (attendance), false (non-attendance) and NULL for any single event.

EDIT:

I just realized that arrays do not behave as I thought in pSQL, so a simple

```
userconfirm bool[]
```

Might suffice. However, I am still having the same problem counting true/false/null values. I will attempt to edit the question below to match this new constraint. I apologize for any errors.

---

I have a column such as

```
userconfirm bool[]
```

Where `userconfirm[314] = true` would mean that user #314 will attend. (false = no attend, NULL = not read/etc).

I'm not sure this is the best solution for this functionality (users announce their attendance to an event), but I am having trouble with an aggregate function on this column.

```
select count(*) from foo where id = 6 AND true = ANY (userconfirm);
```

This only returns 1, and trying to google "counting arrays" does not turn up anything useful.

How would I go about counting the different values for a single event?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`unnest`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) in your SELECT like this:

```
select whatever,
       (select sum(case b when 't' then 1 else 0 end) from unnest(userconfirm) as dt(b))
from your_table
-- ...
```

For example, given this:

```
=> select * from bools;
 id |     bits     
----+--------------
  1 | {t,t,f}
  2 | {t,f}
  3 | {f,f}
  4 | {t,t,t}
  5 | {f,t,t,NULL}
```

You'd get this:

```
=> select id, (select sum(case b when 't' then 1 else 0 end) from unnest(bits) as dt(b)) as trues from bools;
 id | trues 
----+-------
  1 |     2
  2 |     1
  3 |     0
  4 |     3
  5 |     2
```

If that's too ugly, you could write a function:

```
create function count_trues_in(boolean[]) returns bigint as $$
    select sum(case b when 't' then 1 else 0 end)
    from unnest($1) as dt(b)
$$ language sql;
```

and use it to pretty up your query:

```
=> select id, count_trues_in(bits) as trues from bools;
 id | trues 
----+-------
  1 |     2
  2 |     1
  3 |     0
  4 |     3
  5 |     2
```

Comment: That seems to work. And I can reverse it with `'f'` to get the opposite. I don't suppose you'd know how to get a list of the indexes which are true? E.g. have it return `1,4,314`.

Comment: @TLP: I think you could do it with a combination of `unnest` and `generate_series`; `unnest` to open up the array and `generate_series` to provide the index numbers. Then maybe `array_agg` to put them back together.

Comment: @TLP: Or maybe `rank() over` to provide the indexes.

Comment: SQL is making my brain hurt. Maybe it's simplest to try to export some array to PHP and do the processing there. If I could use perl, this wouldn't even be a problem.

Answer (score 4):

You could SUM the array_length function result :

```
SELECT SUM(array_length(userconfirm, 2)) WHERE id = 6;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realized my question has changed. Arrays do not work as I thought (coming from perl). I am using `bool[]` instead. Summing the array length does not seem to be the correct solution, as I get 293 as the sum for an array with two non-null values.

Answer (score 1):

This one may do the trick([unnest](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-array.html)).

```
postgres=# with y(res) as (
postgres(#              with x(a) as (
postgres(#                      values (ARRAY[true,true,false])
postgres(#                      union all
postgres(#                      values (ARRAY[true,null,false])
postgres(#              )
postgres(#              select unnest(a) as res
postgres(#              from x
postgres(#      )
postgres-# select count(*)
postgres-# from y
postgres-# where res;
 count
-------
     3
(1 row)


postgres=#
```

Comment: This seems awfully complicated. And how would I apply this to my table? I'm not comparing two arrays, I want to compare one array to one value.

Comment: The unnest function explodes an array into a table structure (the y subquery). On an array converted to a single column table you can use count(*) on a SQL query evaluating your condition. Cheking for res = true, is the same as checking for res.